# Android Development: TouchEvent

Tags: android, touch, 2d

Im developing a 2d game rightnow.

Im using:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
```

So basicly I want my person.X to increase while I'm holding down the screen.

It both works and don't, first my person do move but I have to spam press the screen.

Isn't there a way like: as long as you touch screen reapeat this code?

//Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return **true** in the onTouchEvent method to show that you have handled the event and to continue to receive touch events (such as `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`).

If you want to keep changing the game state while a user is holding down the screen I suggest running a separate thread (you should already have one?) that will update it separately according a boolean set by a `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and reset by a `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`.

Remember you can access the type of `MotionEvent` by using `MotionEvent.getAction()` (in this case `event.getAction()`)